# MX point to different host then web server

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I have read many answers on the topic, but still it isn't completely clear, I might need help due to the complexity of the matter.

I will explain myself:

We have a DOMAIN name for or email which is hosted at Yahoo, we want that to be kept that way

We bought a HostGator Dedicated Server in order to host the website only.

Can we keep the email on yahoo and the web site working that way?' If so, how can we?

I am not an expert but I'm eager to learn from you. I've seen my settings on the DOMAIN and have two DNS which I suppose one is for mail and the other for the web, but I read it was a backup in case the first one is having trouble, how will it know which way it should go?

I read this but I have not a clear idea hoping you can point me to the right direction.

```
Register mx.example.com as a new A record pointing to 1.2.3.4. Update the MX record for example.com to point to mx.example.com. At this point, you'll have:

example.com.      A   1.2.3.4
mx.example.com    A   1.2.3.4
example.com.      MX  10 mx.example.com.
www.example.com.  A   4.5.6.7

Now wait at least twice the TTL for your records to make sure the old MX record has time to expire from DNS caches.

Next, update the A record for example.com and www.example.com to point to your new site. You'll end up with something along the lines of:

example.com.      A   2.3.4.5
example.com.      MX  10 mx.example.com.
mx.example.com.   A   1.2.3.4
www.example.com.  A   2.3.4.5
```

So as you can see that is an answer I get looking through all the help you provide, but since I don't have it completely clear, I'd like some help from you. I'm deeply sorry for not understanding at all but please correct me

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.

Comment: I do have understanding and I think I can understand eveything I can be taught by you, It is not a barrier and you are not taking the time to really help,  English my be a barrier but not a problem,  I do have find a possible way to work with this, I did research on the matter learning that it is indeed possible but I am having trouble because I apparently cannot configure my MX Records properly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep the e-mail going to yahoo you must put the MX record pointing to yahoo. I don't know them but it should be pretty simple. Since you have already the email working it should already be ok. It should look something like this (you might need more than one).

```
example.com.     86400 IN    MX 10    $mx_server_for_yahoo
```

For the web server you only need to place an A record, and CNAME for other addresses that you want to point to your website:

```
example.com.     86400 IN    A        $Hosted_server_ip  
www.example.com. 86400 IN    CNAME    example.com.
```

Comment: Ok. I'll try and will get to you I  think the problem might be my DOMAIN Provider since I cannot find those settings, It's called Macaria,  I believe I'm doing it wrong perhaps. I understand the MX record configuration, Thank you for helping me.

Comment: The interface changes from a registrar to another but normally it is straight forvward: modify zone, add records.

Comment: @Sven Thanks for the edits, I didn't know how to tab properly...4 spaces so simple...

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm trying this as soon as possible, I'll keep you updated, sorry for the lack of knowledge.